# Would 'quién' be used here or 'quien'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

> No tengo a nadie con **quien** practicar.

Would *quién* be used here or *quien*? Guides online that explain the difference are a little hard for me to understand. Which is grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *quien* because it is working as a relative pronoun that modifies *nadie*.  Notice you can use other structures that modify nadie and it still makes sense:

- no tengo a nadie…

  - interesante.
  - que me hable en chino.
  - de Argelia.

If you wanted to turn it into a question, you'd get *¿Tengo a alguien con quien hablar?* which is a yes/no question.  Therefore, the *quien* is demonstratably not an interrogative pronoun — it's still modifying *alguien*.

You only use *quién* when it's being used as an interrogative.  To do that in your sentence, you'd need to say something like

> No tengo con quién practicar

...whose associated question would *¿Quién tengo con que <sub>(puedo)</sub>* hablar?  Notice how it is clearly functioning here as an interrogative word, and not a relative pronoun.  Otherwise, leaving it as *No tengo a nadie con quién practicar* is literally saying "I don't have anyone (along) with—who was that again?— to practice," which is a rather odd sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped clear some stuff up. And sorry this is a little belated, but the literal translation would be "I do not have anyone with whom to practice" or more naturally "I do not have anyone to practice with". Are you saying my sentence in Spanish doesn't sound natural to you?

Comment: @James the odd sounding gloss I gave is for if you opted to accent it. Without the accent, it is a perfectly natural sounding sentence.

Comment: Okay, great. I get what you mean now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The answer is right, and even though the counterexample is right too, it is a very specific case of accenting _quien_. Moreover, the _associated question_ is not grammatically right. It would be _¿Con quién (puedo) practicar?_

Answer (score 1):

You must use "quien" when you have to refer about a person. Example:

> Ella es quien bailó toda la noche.

You must use "quién" when is a question (direct or indirect). Example:

> No sé quién comió mi comida.

This is  a indirect question (here is where it gets a little confusing, something that you can do is convert the sentence to a direct question):

> ¿Quién se comió mi comida?

Because `no tengo nadie con quién practicar` is a indirect question: ¿Quién practicará conmigo?  you have to use "Quién"