# ¿"quien" y "donde" se escriben con tilde en este caso?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, pronombre-interrogativo

Es claro para mí que "quién" y "dónde" se escriben con tilde cuando forman parte de una frase interrogativa o exclamativa y no cuando son pronombres relativos, pero aunque miro todos los ejemplos del [artículo de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde) no me queda claro cómo clasificarlos en esta frase.

> Para mejorar el uso de la información hay que saber **quien** la maneja y **donde** está.

Para mí no es una exclamación ni una interrogación pero no me queda claro si debe escribirse

> Para mejorar el uso de la información hay que saber **quién** la maneja y **dónde** está.

Para contribuir aún más a mi confusión, la RAE provee ejemplos en los que es válido usar o no la tilde.

> El problema es que no hay con qué/que alimentar a tanta gente.
>
> Ya ha encontrado quién/quien le quiera y no necesita nada más.
>
> Buscó dónde/donde sentarse, pero no había asientos libres.
>
> No tenía cómo/como defenderse de las acusaciones.

Pienso que  **"ha encontrado quien/quién le quiera"** y **"hay que saber quien/quién la maneja"** son dos frases muy similares y por lo tanto es válido usar o no la tilde pero quiero la opinión del foro.

La pregunta que encuentro más cercana en SE es [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12821/would-qui%C3%A9n-be-used-here-or-quien) pero ese caso sí es claro para mí.

Comment: No son pronombres relativos, porque no se relacionan con el sustantivo. Lo correcto es usar las tildes.

Comment: Pues me han dejado "plof" los de la RAE porque yo diría que "Ya ha encontrado quién le quiera" y "No tenía como defenderse de las acusaciones" están mal. Dicho esto, yo también creo que los ejemplos que pones van con tilde.

Comment: Hay una pregunta relacionada: [¿Qué propósito tiene el acento en una pregunta?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14848/6915). La respuesta que da guifa es muy aclaratoria: el pronombre interrogativo _reemplaza_ una palabra desconocida mientras que el relativo _indica_ una palabra que ya fue dicha antes.

Comment: Interesante. Gracias @Rodrigo. Espero que guifa se pase por aquí y me de su apreciación. Debe estar de vacaciones al igual que fedorqui y Yay que no se han dejado escuchar.

Comment: @DGaleano de vacaciones precisamente no, aunque no me quejo nada de «tener que» estar en Coímbra para mis investigaciones :-)   Eso dicho, vi la pregunta y aún estoy en escribir la respuesta.  Ya escribí la parte sobre «que/qué», ahora solo me hace falta escribir sobre «dónde/donde» que todavía no he pensando en algunos buenos ejemplos para dar como un tipo de prueba general.

Comment: @guifa que gusto me da saber que hay una respuesta en camino.

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso lo correcto sería que ambos lleven acento, ya que el **quién** y el **dónde** no indican a alguien en específico que ya ha sido mencionado o que se conoce.

Un ejemplo en el que no llevarían acento es el siguiente.

> Mi mejor amigo, que nació en México, donde se encuentra actualmente, es una persona a quien conozco bien.

En este caso no se utiliza el acento debido a que el lugar y la persona de quien se habla, han sido mencionados antes, y solo se utiliza Quien y Donde para evitar repetir el sustantivo.

Espero que con el ejemplo logres distinguir más fácilmente si es correcto utilizar el acento.

Comment: Estoy seguro de que DGaleano logra distinguir entre la tilde y el pronombre relativo. Creo que lo que causa confusión aquí se debe mayoritariamente a que la RAE entrega esos ejemplos con y sin tilde.

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso sí que llevaría acento, ya que es una subordinada interrogativa: se está realizando una pregunta, aunque no directamente.

*Para mejorar el uso de la información hay que saber quién la maneja y dónde está*
¿Quién la maneja? ¿Dónde está?

Si no se puede hacer en modo pregunta, normalmente se escriben sin acento:
*El problema es que no hay con qué/que alimentar a tanta gente.*
¿Qué alimentar a tanta gente? No tiene sentido. Esto es por que no está realizando una pregunta indirecta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Según la RAE es válido decir "ha encontrado **quien** le quiera" y según tu lógica se puede decir en modo pregunta ¿ha  encontrado quién le quiera?. ¿Ves el punto?

Comment: No es exactamente lo que yo he dicho, ya que a lo que yo me refiero cuando hablo de modo pregunta es empezar directamente con el pronombre interrogativo. En este caso sería ¿Quién le quiera? y no sirve.