# ¿Han existido alguna vez en el idioma español acentos diferentes al agudo?

Tags: historia, acentuación

Como todos sabemos, en el idioma español se usan los acentos agudos (´), además de la diéresis (¨) que afecta a la u en algunas palabras. Pero, ¿han existido en algún momento de la historia palabras en español que llevaran acentos graves (`) o circunflejos (^)?

Para acotar la respuesta, entendamos español como el hablado desde el siglo XVI (el conocido como *español medio* o *áurico*).

Comment: Pues parece ser que sí: en [Ortografía del español # Acentuación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Acentuaci.C3.B3n) se lee _Tras el abandono del acento circunflejo ( ^ ) en el siglo XIX, el español emplea como diacrítico exclusivamente el acento agudo ( ´ ), que se coloca sobre la vocal central de una sílaba para indicar que esta es tónica en algunos casos._ Y allí, _El signo, introducido por la RAE  en el siglo XVIII, señalaba que ch y x se pronunciaban [k] y [ks] (...). Ejemplos: châracteres, exâcto_. Duró poco tiempo, vaya.

Comment: @fedorqui esto de escribir como comentarios respuestas perfectamente válidas se está convirtiendo en una manía en este sitio... :)

Comment: [Aquí](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KnSbsIzbkogPocTb) también hay para una buena respuesta. A ver si luego tengo algún momento, o alguien encuentra información extra al respecto.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ya... cuando de hecho lo bueno sería que mucha gente contestara, pues en general [hay pocas respuestas por pregunta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language). Supongo que es más fácil comentar que responder jaja Escribo una respuesta y ruego que esto no sea impedimento para que otros contesten: cuanto más puntos de vista y recursos, mejor; no hay necesidad de que todo esté en la misma respuesta.

Comment: @Yay en Ngram se ve el [ámbito temporal de uso de à](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=1800&corpus=21&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0). Sin embargo, no aparecen ni _exâmen_ ni _monarchîa_ ni _châracteres_ ni _exâcto_. Sí que debió de durar poco...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo En el CORDE aparecen 60 casos en 12 documentos, todos entre 1770 y 1827, para *exâmen*. Un ejemplo:  "En quanto á lo de ahuyentar las tempestades debe preceder mayor exâmen y observarse la circunspeccion debida ántes de señalar la causa de los fenómenos, que pueden ser puramente naturales." 
(Cavanilles, Antonio José, 1797). *Exâcto* aparece por la misma época y no aparecen *monarchîa* o *châracteres*.

Comment: @Yay me voy a tener que acostumbrar a consultar el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) para mis pesquisas lingüísticas...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Es un recurso muy bueno, pero si lo vas a usar en alguna respuesta te recomiendo que añadas pantallazos porque los links se caen.

Comment: @Yay ¡gracias por el apunte! He añadido el CORDE a [la lista de recursos online](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/74/12637), y he añadido también la diferencia entre este y el CREA.

Comment: Como dice Carlos se volvió vicio comentar en lugar de responder y otra cosa que se volvió vicio es aceptar muy rápidamente la primera respuesta que aparece. Eso es lo que desanima a otros a responder y genera lo que dice fedroqui de que haya muy pocas respuestas por cada pregunta. A propósito sigo esperando la [respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17399/quien-y-donde-se-escriben-con-tilde-en-este-caso) de @guifa jajaja o al menos una más.

Comment: @DGaleano que haya una respuesta aceptada no es impedimento para añadir otras si pueden complementarla. De hecho, la marca de respuesta aceptada se puede desmarcar si se considera que una nueva respuesta es mejor que la anterior.

Comment: Carlos, eso lo sé pero digo que eso es lo que desanima, sobretodo a los nuevos. Las estadísticas que analiza @fedorqui lo confirman.

Comment: @DGaleano las estadísticas confirman que hay pocas respuestas por pregunta, es decir, confirman el hecho, pero no la causa del mismo. Yo mismo cuando llegué a este sitio lo primero que hice fue repasar preguntas antiguas para añadir más datos que conocía y que complementaban respuestas aceptadas. Eso ya depende de cada uno. En todo caso, podemos abrir una discusión en meta si de verdad te preocupa el asunto y crees que debería tratarse más en profundidad.

Comment: @DGaleano sí, es un tema complicado. Supongo que al ser un sitio pequeño con pocos usuarios frecuentes y con buena relación entre ellos, se genera un compadreo que lleva a no querer "pisar" la respuesta de otros, sino a complementarla con comentarios y ser exquisito respetando lo que uno ya apuntó en los comentrios. Es curioso porque en [so] se sufre de lo contrario: [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/209901), con muchos contestando lo mismo a la caza de votos. Dicho lo cual, no creo que sea un problema pero sí una cosa a tener en cuenta: contestemos más, ¡que es gratis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La Wikipedia nos resuelve la duda.

En su artículo [Ortografía del español, sección Acentuación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Acentuaci.C3.B3n) observamos:

> Tras el abandono del [acento circunflejo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_circunflejo) ( ^ ) en el siglo XIX, el
>   español emplea como diacrítico exclusivamente el [acento agudo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_agudo) ( ´
>   ), que se coloca sobre la vocal central de una sílaba para indicar que
>   esta es [tónica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_pros%C3%B3dico) en algunos casos.

La curiosidad nos mueve a visitar la sección de acento circunflejo arriba indicada, donde leemos:

> El signo, introducido por la Real Academia en el siglo XVIII, señalaba
>   que ch y x se pronunciaban [k] y [ks] respectivamente en la vocal
>   siguiente, ya que tales palabras eran préstamos del latín o del
>   griego. Ejemplos: châracteres, exâcto. Sin embargo, si el uso de este
>   acento contradecía el uso del acento agudo, se le daba prioridad al
>   segundo: chímica (y no chîmica). También, si una palabra terminaba en
>   x, no se marcaba su pronunciación [x] en ninguna vocal cercana al no
>   ser seguida de vocal: relox (hoy: reloj). En los primeros textos, el
>   circunflejo podía alternar con el grave en usos similares (â, cargarâ,
>   despachô) o utilizarse en voces como fê o vêr para indicar la
>   presencia original de una doble vocal (fee, veer; hoy: fe, ver).
>   También podía aparecer la palabra como baxîos, traîa, tenîa, oîa (en
>   estas últimas, indicaba un hiato o ruptura del diptongo), recordando
>   su empleo en griego con palabras con estas mismas terminaciones. El
>   acento agudo se usaba raramente y casi siempre en posición interior de
>   palabra. No obstante las tendencias descritas, hay que señalar que, en
>   esa primera época, el uso de los diferentes tipos de acento era, por
>   lo general, irregular e inconsistente incluso dentro de una misma
>   obra.
>
> **Este signo (^) luego fue abandonado rápidamente en el mismo siglo, después de que el uso de ch con pronunciación [k] y de x con
>   pronunciación [x] se abandonaran a favor de c/qu y j/g (como en relox
>   o dixe), volviéndolo de nula utilidad.**

Comment: Partiendo de Ngram se pueden encontrar textos que incluyen la preposición _à_ o el sustantivo _fê_. ¡Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: @Charlie Con acento **grave** hay casos para todas las vocales. En el Diccionario de Autoridades, por ejemplo, aparecen tanto la **ò** c1omo la **à** en el artículo "SODOMIA"